# Tips to make simulated images look more realistic?

Tags: python, data-science, simulation

I am currently simulating some protein diffusion with python. This is my procedure

1. Have some random walkers across a canvas of 32x32 pixels
2. Apply a Gaussian convolution filter to smooth out the random walkers pixels
3. Apply some random noise

I obtain something like this

[image]

Where each pixel has an associated intensity value.

I am looking for ways to make this look more realistic. Particularly, maybe some ways to make the blobs more irregular? Maybe some spots of continuous brightness, I don't know. Any suggestions? I wish to have something that looks like this

[image]